# query string with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

i have a problem with a query string in Laravel 5.6

I have this two entities, ER Schema: 
[image: ER Schema]

and related model:
[Note model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4YFA.png)
[Location model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WevpH.png)

My problem is that I have to select all notes in a certain location passing as query string parameters latitude and longitude.

A query string could be:

```
homestead.test/api/notes?lat=45.5432&long=43.6543&max_distance=1.1
```

I try to build a query [Here the NoteController code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQBG7.png), but there is a problem:

Actually the output show me every note.
This is a [postman output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETZu7.png) and in addition to the notes in the right location, I also return those with location = null. Going to see in the database these notes have only one parameter that coincides with those passed in query string. Theoretically it should not return them and I can not take them off in any way. could someone help me?

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance

Comment: please provide codes in text format rather than images in your question.

Comment: Hello @Francesco and welcome to SO, codes should be pasted in the question for easier read and quicker response

Answer (score 0):

```
Node::with(['location' => function($query) use ($latitude, $longitude){
    $query->where('latitude', $latitude);
    $query->where('longitude', $longitude);
}])->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can help someone, I solved the problem in this way.

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    if($request->has('lat') &&
        $request->has('long')) {

        $lat1 = $request->query('lat');
        $long1 = $request->query('long');
        $max_distance = $request->query('max_distance');

        $notes = Note::All();

        foreach ($notes as $key => $value) {

            if($value->location != null) {
                $lat2 = $value->location->latitude;
                $long2 = $value->location->longitude;
                $distance = sqrt(pow($lat2-$lat1, 2) + pow($long2-$long1, 2));

                if($distance > $max_distance) {
                    $notes->forget($key);
                }    
            } else {
                $notes->forget($key);
            }

        }

        return $notes;
    }
    return Note::All();
```